React canvas not covering screen
I am using a library called 'Mafs' to do math animations and this is supposed to create a coordinate grid that covers the screen, but there's whitespace and I can't figure out why (Result)
import React from 'react';
import { Mafs, Coordinates } from 'mafs';
import 'mafs/core.css'; // Ensure you import the core stylesheet for Mafs

function Example() {
  return (
    <Mafs>
      <Coordinates.Cartesian />
    </Mafs>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh', margin: 0 }}>
      <Example />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


change height to min-height it should fix the white space.

Can you please try this below solution?
import React from 'react';
import { Mafs, Coordinates } from 'mafs';
import 'mafs/core.css'; 

function Example() {
  return (
    <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, display: 'flex' }}>
      <Mafs style={{ flexGrow: 1 }} >
        <Coordinates.Cartesian />
      </Mafs>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh', margin: 0, display: 'flex' }}>
      <Example />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

